# How do I use geolocation alternative tutorial for weather?

Tags: jquery, weather

I found this tutorial - http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/weather-web-app-geolocation-revisited/

But it uses geolocation. Does anyone know how to change this so I can just plug in a location or use something liked http://freegeoip.net to get a location? I have been trying but I end up with an error code, or it just never loads.

Answer (score 0):

This is looking pretty straight forward.

Remove that:

```
// Does this browser support geolocation?
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
}
else{
    showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
}
```

And call that with your own coordinates:

```
function locationSuccess(position)
```

The position parameter can have any structure you desire, just be sure to updated those lines to match your variables.

```
var weatherAPI = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat='+position.coords.latitude+
                                '&lon='+position.coords.longitude+'&callback=?'
```

You want to manually call locationSuccess instead of the piece of code checking if geolocation is available.